# Sliding window without copying data in armadillo

Tags: c++, armadillo

Suppose I have large armadillo matrix like the following:

```
9 4 8 6 7 ...
5 1 9 4 5 ...
6 6 4 1 2 ...
```

and I want to slide over this big matrix with a small window of width 3, e.g

```
9 4 8
5 1 9
6 6 4

4 8 6
1 9 4
6 4 1

8 6 7
9 4 5
4 1 2

...
```

but I don't want to copy these data to a new matrix, instead 
I want to reuse the information already existing in RAM.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, using [`submat`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat), which creates submatrix views:

```
using namespace arma;
const unsigned total_rows = 10;
const unsigned total_cols = 10;

mat all_data(total_rows, total_cols);
// fill your data here
// ...

const unsigned window_rows = 3;
const unsigned window_cols = 3;

const auto num_windows_w = total_cols - window_cols;
const auto num_windows_h = total_rows - window_rows;
for (unsigned row_start = 0; row_start < num_windows_h; ++row_start) {
  for (unsigned col_start = 0; col_start < num_windows_w; ++col_start) {
    auto window = all_data.submat(row_start, col_start, row_start + window_rows, col_start + window_cols);
    // process your window here
    //...
  }
}
```

You can also use `mat::span` to perform the same kind of operations.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with that window further on. If you use a `submat` view and pass it on to do some further matrix manipulations like multiplying it with another matrix or with a vector, I am pretty sure that armadillo will unfortunately create a copy of your matrix.

In your case I think it is however possible without creating any copies, but only if your windows have the same amount of *rows* as the original matrix. The reason for this is that armadillo uses a [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_major) data layout (i.e. it stores the columns consecutively in memory). The data in your windows are thus also consecutive rows of your original matrix.

You can then use the advanced constructor [`mat(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = false)`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat%20%60%60mat%60%60) that directly takes a pointer to memory. By setting `copy_aux_mem = false` you can also specify to directly use that memory and not copy it.

```
const unsigned m = 3;
const unsigned n = 10;

mat M(m,n,fill::randn);
M.print("M");

const unsigned dpos = m;
unsigned pos = 0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i <= n-m ; ++i)
{
    mat tmp(&M.memptr()[pos],m,m,false);
    cout<<i+1<<endl;
    tmp.print();
    // your further manipulations here
    pos += dpos;
}
```

If you use this you must make sure however to remain within the bounds of your matrix, as no armadillo range checking will capture any mistakes here.